# after installing thymeleaf plugin, in my spring tool suite application.properties file looks like this. How to resolve it?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, application.properties, spring-thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDq0a.png)

after installing thymeleaf plugin, in my spring tool suite application.properties file looks like this. How to resolve it?

I've tried to reinstall web developer tools from eclipse marketplace which resolved same error with HTML & CSS files.

Comment: some more details (e.g. the versions that you use, where you installed the plugin from, which version of it, etc. and steps how to reproduce this could be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this link in your project:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```